# How to add to a nested collection in oData

Tags: odata

If I had a collection `/Events(123)/Registrants`, and I wanted to add a `Person` to that collection, how would I do something like that. 
I tried `POSTing` a `Person` to that url, but I get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me for not reading the [oData specification](http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/operations#CreatingLinksbetweenEntries).

```
POST /OData/OData.svc/Events(123)/$links/Registrants HTTP/1.1
Host: services.odata.org
DataServiceVersion: 1.0
MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0
Content-Length: 159
Content-Type: application/xml
<uri xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Person(10)
</uri>
```